# CSS margin prevents area from beeing clickable

Tags: html, css

I am enclosing the main content of my page into a div which has a top margin of 80px like in the screenshot:

[image]

This works, the problem is that there is a leaderboard banner just above it and the div prevents the banner to be clickable just for the area illustrated in green.

The code is nothing special:

```
#content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 80px 10px 15px;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

The problem also occurs if I use margin instead of padding.

How could I maintain the margin/padding and in the same time keep the leaderboard clickable?

Comment: what's the css of that "leaderboard" and the HTML of both and their container?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your css :

```
#content{
    z-index: 1;
}

#yourBanner{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```